# View all folders and subfolders with script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Let's say I have a folder F1, with two subfolders (F2 and F3). And subfolder F2 contains another folder F4. With this code run when I'm inside F1:
`find . -type d`
It will list the folders as:

```
F2
F3
F2/F4
```

Is there a way to list them as:

```
F2
F3
F4
```

Comment: With GNU `find`, you can try `find -type d -printf '%f\n'`

Comment: I added the last part but it made no difference :(

Comment: Then this may work: `find -type d | sed 's/.*\///'`

Comment: As with the other answer, I had a duplicate of my file so ran the wrong one. The first line works wonders. Thank you

Comment: What does '%f\n' do?

Comment: Prints the basename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `grep` after using `find` as below:

```
find . -type d | grep -oP '(?<=/)\w+$';
```

Comment: This one does the same as well :(

Comment: Online shell result: https://onlinegdb.com/e8P-RQtyN. This should work, are you sure if you are using it right?

Comment: I am so sorry! My file had copied so I ran old version.. It works :D